# WCF connect to Websocket server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, websocket

Which library should i use to connect my WCF Service (remote) to a Websocket server ?

I found this library Microsoft.ServiceModel.Websocket.dll but i didn't found how to use in the case where the webservice is the client and not the server.

PS : I'm using .net 4.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a WCF binding with websocket protocol support. Unfortunately it doesn't exist in .net 4.0.

It [will be available](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338789/What-s-new-in-WCF-4-5-WebSocket-support-Part-1-of) in .net 4.5, though.

Comment: is there another library open source to do that job ? or is it possible to use the new dll for the newest framework ?